# Syntax error running Python script in Java Process

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I have a script in python that should receive two PDF files and output an image. It works fine in the terminal but when I try to run it in a Java process using process builder it gives me a syntax error and I am not sure why.

I am using python3 with the command (in the terminal):

```
python3 /pathToMyPythonScript/command_line.py /Users/myname/Desktop/one.pdf /Users/myname/Desktop/two.pdf > /Users/myname/Desktop/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png
```

**It works and produces the desired output.**

also tried:

/usr/local/bin/python3 /pathtomypythonscript/command_line.py /Users/myname/Desktop/one.pdf /Users/myname/Desktop/two.pdf > /Users/myname/Desktop/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png

**and it also works fine.**

When I call the same script in my java code using the following code:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/python3", fileOneLocation, fileTwoLocation, outputFileDestination).inheritIO().start();
```

all variables are declared and all files exist.

**My eclipse console output is an error:**

```
File "/Users/myname/Desktop/one.pdf", line 1
    %PDF-1.3
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I missing here? It works fine in terminal but not in Java.

Comment: In your Java code, shouldn't there be the python file to run? Currently there only is a call to python and then passing the pdfs - but not your actual Python script

Comment: @hage From what I read Java process works with a command and not a script. You're probably thinking of a solution using Jython or so.

Comment: Nevermind @hage you were right. I feel so bad for not noticing something like this. Thank you. Forgot to add the scriptPathVariable in the Process Builder.

Comment: No. In your commandline example, you call `python command_line.py one.pdf two.pdf` But in your Java code there is no reference to your python script and the interpreter thinks that its first argument is the script - but it actually is a pdf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer:

You forgot to mention your actual python script in the `ProcessBuilder`